# Как завершить вызов(звонок)?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день! Целый день безрезультатно пытаюсь найти ответ на вопрос как можно завершить звонок на телефоне? Сделать вызов можно с помощью Intent в BroadcastReceiver можно получить состояние телефона, а как можно сбросить вызов? В общем как программно положить трубку? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (myBundle != null) {
        System.out.println("--------Not null-----");
        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
                String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                System.out.println("--------in state-----");
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    // Incoming call
                    String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    System.out.println("--------------my number---------" + incomingNumber);

// this is main section of the code,. could also be use for particular number.
                    // Get the boring old TelephonyManager.
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                    // Get the getITelephony() method
                    Class<?> classTelephony = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                    Method methodGetITelephony = classTelephony.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

                    // Ignore that the method is supposed to be private
                    methodGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);

                    // Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
                    Object telephonyInterface = methodGetITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);

                    // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
                    Class<?> telephonyInterfaceClass = Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
                    Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");

                    // Invoke endCall()
                    methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { // Many things can go wrong with reflection calls
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

К ответу gadfil, необходимо добавить, что это все делается в `BroadcastReceiver`.

И не забыть добавить в манифест

```
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```